# PyQt5 - Increase main window size by pressing a button

Tags: pyqt, resize, pyqt5

I currently have a window which size is 775x380 and a button. I want to increase the height of my window to 775x780 when I click the button, but for some reason is not working. This is the function I call when pressing the button (dock, which has "+" text on it from the start):

```
def resize(self):
    if self.dock.text() == '+':
        print('increase size')
        self.resize(775,780)
        self.dock.setText("-")
    else:
        print('decrease size')
        self.resize(775,380)
        self.dock.setText("+")
```

The print commands are more for debugging and they work fine, but for some reason the 'self.resize(775,780)' is not working. The window remains the same size and the button changes it's text from '+' to '-' and viceversa.

Edit for clarification: resize() is a function within class MainWindow(object)
Edit 2: Here is the whole code I'm using (the relevant part of the code at least)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        #MAIN WINDOW
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(775, 340)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        #APPLY BUTTON
        self.apply = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.apply.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 10, 75, 25))
        self.apply.setText("Apply")
        self.apply.setObjectName("apply")

        #REREF BUTTON
        self.reref = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.reref.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 10, 75, 25))
        self.reref.setText("Re Ref")
        self.reref.setObjectName("reref")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1324, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        #RESIZE BUTTON
        self.dock = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.dock.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-1, 280, 777, 30))
        self.dock.setText("+")
        self.dock.setObjectName("dock")
        #
        self.apply.clicked.connect(self._big)
        self.reref.clicked.connect(self._small)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def _big(self):
        self.resize(775,780)
    def _small(self):
        self.resize(775,340)

    def start(self):
        import sys
        if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
            app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        else:
            app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
        app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
        VolatilityManager = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(VolatilityManager)
        VolatilityManager.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.start()
```

Comment: Well, `resize` calls itself with the wrong arguments, so that will raise an error. But even if it didn't, you'd get an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Name your resize() method something else so it won't override the QMainWindow method.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.expand_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Expand', self)
        self.contract_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Contract', self)
        layout.addWidget(self.expand_btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.contract_btn)

        self.expand_btn.clicked.connect(self._expand)
        self.contract_btn.clicked.connect(self._contract)

    def _expand(self):
        self.resize(775,780)
    def _contract(self):
        self.resize(775,380)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Your code works for me, but even if I change the name of my function my code still doesn't work. Instead of `def __init__(self, parent=None)` I have a function called `def setupUi(self, MainWindow)`, could that be it? I will edit now my first post to put my whole code. I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: Solved! Apparently, and I don't know why, if I change the setupUi function for an `__init__` function and adjust the rest of the code for it (e.g., changing `MainWindow` in the code with `self`, etc) it works, although I don't understand why. Thanks a lot for your code!

Comment: That's why its always important to post a runnable version of your code.  You may have multiple problems.  It is near impossible to explain problems with code that isn't posted.